# Slicing the last 2 columns of a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

How can I slice the last 2 columns of a numpy array?

for example:
`A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])`
and I want to get B as the last 2 columns of A which is `[[2, 3], [5, 6]]`

I know that I can index it from start of the array such as `B = A[:, 1:3]`. But I am looking for a general form to slice A by indexing from the end as the number of columns for A changes in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
>>> A[:,[-2,-1]]
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 6]])
```

A generalised method to get the last n rows can be

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3,4],[4, 5, 6,7]]) 
>>> A[:,-3:]
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```